# UWP render 3D model in a

Tags: 3d, win-universal-app, render

I'm writing a C# Universal Windows Application that loads a model from a .obj file and I would like to render that model so that the user can rotate it and scale it. Is there a way to render it in the app? Preferably in the same window? Something like the Map control, it's wrapped inside the app but still interactive.

Comment: did you find solution ?

Comment: As I didn't have enough time and experience I decided not to implement the feature, but as I mentioned in a different comment, I found out about <SwapChainPanel /> which then you can pass to a C++/CLI component (if your app is in C# for example), initialize DirectX there and bind the swapchain to the panel. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel

Answer (score 2):

I found this [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/07/17/uwp-3d-transformation/) for Windows 8.1 phone that tells us to use [PlaneProjection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/3-d-perspective-effects).

```
 <StackPanel.Projection>        
    <PlaneProjection RotationX="-35" RotationY="-35" RotationZ="15"  />    
</StackPanel.Projection>
```

[DirectX may be the answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31ee3f41-b1d8-4924-9b3f-93e4a4d74609/uwpdirectx-11loading-3d-model-from-file?forum=wpdevelop) to loading the obj file. "  DirectX has limited features when it comes to loading a 3D model: It is recommended to use the DirectXTK (toolkit) to handle them. The 3D model file formats that it supports are: .CMO, .SDKMESH and .VBO. It should support .OBJ too (if my memory serves me well)...."
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-directx-game-development-blending-and-models-8491?l=uG7SBIYz_8604984382

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't really solve my problem and I already found a solution with <SwapChainPanel />, I can do the file loading myself. Appreciate your help though.