# UWP 3d model loading

Tags: model, 3d, load, uwp

I have searched everywhere but can not find an answer how could I load a 3d model (.obj/.fbx...) into UWP. I tried it with Helix, but it doesn't work well on the UWP yet. I would like to rotate this model after its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<SwapChainPanel />`

Here is the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel.aspx) on it

Here is a [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b#content) on how to use it. The tutorial is for Windows 8 but there are comments from people using this in UWP.

All of this was found (On Bing) in one search.

This was the StackOverflow question that lead me to the answer. Look at the first comment on the first answer [UWP render 3D model in a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520221/uwp-render-3d-model-in-a)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the Problem is that non of these is with combination Xaml and C# or Xaml and C++

Comment: Uhhh the tutorial I posted is literally called "XAML SwapChainPanel DirectX interop sample"

Comment: That´s right, but they are not loading 3d models there ... they are drawing them

Comment: How does Unity do it? That's the recommended way to load 3D models in UWP