# Can I import and show a 3D file (e.g. exported from Blender) in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, 3d, blender

I want to show in a UWP app a 3D object, made in Bender, that can be rotated 360 degrees on the horizontal axis

Comment: Maybe this doc can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/implementing-3d-app-launchers

Comment: @Vincent It not solve

Comment: Then Unity maybe useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395185/uwp-3d-model-loading